# add loading animation during content replacing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage generated server-side by ASP.net, I can't edit the source code of the page, I can only add HTML, CSS and Javascript.

The page uses an old tables-based layout and the entire document is not well written.
I use jQuery to fetch all the contents of the page (artices, images, links etc) and then I insert them in a new HTML page using jQuery.
When the page is ready, I replace the old page with the new one using:

```
var template = "my long HTML page generated by jQuery before this line";
var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
newDoc.write(template);
newDoc.close();
```

In this way also the `<script>` tags that I have in my new page will be executed correctly, everything perfect.

My only problem is that while the page is replaced, everything becomes white for ~1 second.

I need to avoid that blank flash, so I'd like to put a loading page during the replace process.

**NB:** I'm not using Ajax, I just use jQuery to store in variables the contents of the page where my script runs.

I've tried hiding the entire page and applying a loading image on the body, but obviously it doesn't works, the page becomes white for 1 second as usual.

Solutions?

Comment: is it ajax request that get/generate the content?

Comment: no, I take the informations from the same page where the script is ran

Comment: can you create a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: you can't notice the white flash with not lot of data btw http://jsfiddle.net/89xth/

Comment: What you're talking about has HUGE design issues. Rethink whatever you're doing and get it right to begin with, rather making your user wait a second while you replace things that shouldn't be there with data that is already available...what?!

Comment: I can't edit the way the page is generated, I can only use javascript to edit it.

Comment: By the way, it sounds to me like you're replacing the document then preparing the new one. Be sure that you are hiding/removing the original content, preparing the new document entirely, THEN replacing the document. That way all of your content is ready to append. To be more specific, you need to make sure all of your dom elements are already created and can be added to the page with a single action - like an `append()`. If all of your content is text at this point rather than actual dom elements, it could take some time for all the html to be created. See my new answer.

Comment: I prepare everything and store it in a variable, then I replace the document with the HTML stored in the variable.

Comment: You won't get over this, chances are on slower PC's they will probably see a white screen for 2-5 seconds. I know because i have shamefully done this before on a **eBay Store** and regenerated the whole page, It's such a silly idea.

Comment: I'm using a substantially outdated laptop (2.10Ghz, 3gb ram) and the document replace is instant in my example.

Comment: @Pinocchio I've not other solutions so this is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example as you have described where there is no "white" flash. I made a massive sample html document to exaggerate things. As soon as it loads, I replace it with a loading message, then prepare the new content. After the new content is ready, I replace the old document with the new one and then add the new content to it. Smooth and fast. I still think what you are doing is a disaster, but if you must,

View this in chrome!
[here's an example (click here for live demo).](http://plnkr.co/edit/9PO98rsm4xBwONhVTZIn?p=preview)

```
var script = '<script>console.log("New Document script tag is working.");</script>';
var newDoc = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>'+script+'</head><body></body></html>';

var loading = document.createElement('p');
loading.innerText = 'Loading...';

$(document).ready(function() {
  var content = $('body').contents(); //the content of the old document body
  $('body').html(loading);

  setTimeout(function() { //slow things down for this example
    for (var i=0, contentLen=content.length; i<contentLen; ++i) { //prepare the new content
      var text = content[i].innerText;
      if (text) { 
        text+= ' This text is from the old document, with new stuff added.';
        content[i].innerText = text;
      }
    }

    document.open(); //replace doc
    document.write(newDoc);
    document.close();

    $('body').html(content); //immediately add new content

    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js";
    script.onload = function() {
      console.log(angular);
      console.log('New Library Added.');
    };
    document.body.appendChild(script);

  }, 1500); //like I said, this is just to exaggerate the load, ignore it
});
```

Comment: thank you, I've already tried this solution but I have problems because I add in the new page some included javascript that won't load in this way.

Comment: *sigh*. Once again, what are you talking about?!? There is no satisfactory answer for you. Ask a better question, man!

Comment: sorry? what's the problem? I'm asking something that should have a solution, and the question is pretty clear. If you don't know the answer please skip this question.

Comment: Well, it seems to me that the question is pretty bad, to merit 3 downvotes. So please, don't hate on good answers when the question itself is awful.

Comment: @CCInc the asker's comment doesn't seem like hate. It rather seems like a cry for help that is unlikely to be possible to answer helpfully.

Comment: @CCInc Sorry. I mean, there is no hate in Foxy's comment. M59 seems to have overreacted instead ([he's already apologised](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/11664181#11664181)). It is not always out of spite when an asker does not appreciate an answer. It is more likely he's just asking for further help.

Comment: That's just a cultural thing (hate is often used more casually to mean "negative"). Anyway, I'm obsessive, so I updated my answer and live demo again to demonstrate two ways in which javascript can be inserted into your new document. I find that to be basically irrelevant to your post, as it doesn't really have anything to do with document replacement or a loading animation.